# External file with breakpoints continuously added to solution at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This has been driving me crazy and cutting down on my productivity all day. At one point for debugging I dragged an external file from another project into my current solution (Visual Studio 2010) so I could debug it as the class defined in it was being used by the solution I'm working on.

That was all well and good and after I was done I removed it from the solution and everything was normal. At some point however Visual Studio has decided that every single time I run my solution it will bring the external file back in as well as replacing the breakpoints that I used way back when for debugging. No matter how many times I remove the breakpoints and remove the external file from my solution this continues to happen every time I run.

I'm guessing there is some kind of file or setting saved somewhere that's telling VS to do this? Could anyone help me figure things out so I don't have to deal with breakpoints in a file I don't currently care about every time I need to run my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After stopping the debugger. Delete that break point manually either by opening that file or from the list of break points. Yes, visual studio stores this as part of the pdb file. Deleting that file is also an option if you don't mind losing all the debug information.

Comment: Thank you deleting the .pdb files did the trick. That was driving me insane